# on change event is not being triggered via ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

whenever I enter my househould ID. it would load records and input ID chli_hh_id will be populated also. and if the input #cli_hh_id has been populated. the href=" is not being triggered. kindly help please.. thanks :)

here are my input textboxes.

```
                    <input type="text" id = "hh_id" name = "hh_id" placeholder="Please enter Household ID" class = "form-control"  href="<?=base_url('location/hh_members')?>">
                <input type="text" id = "cli_hh_id" name = "cli_hh_id" class = "form-control"  href="<?=base_url('location/cli_hh')?>">
```

Here is my js on the #hh_id. there's no problem here.

```
    $(document)
.on('change', '#hh_id', function(){

    var hh_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href') + '/' + hh_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var html = ""; 
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += "<option  data-cli_hh_id = '"+data[i].cli_hh_id+"' data-entry_id = '"+data[i].entry_id+"' data-my_name = '"+data[i].my_name+"' data-sex = '"+data[i].sex+"' data-brgy = '"+data[i].brgy+"' data-muncity = '"+data[i].muncity+"' data-province = '"+data[i].province+"' data-region = '"+data[i].region+"' value='"+data[i].value+"'>"+data[i].value+"</option>";
            };
            $('#full_name').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

This is where i encounter my problem. this is not being triggered when it has a value on it. :(

```
    $(document)
.on('change', '#cli_hh_id', function(){
alert('Is this loading?');
    var cli_hh_id = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href') + '/' + cli_hh_id,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var html = ""; 
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += "<p>"+ data[i].key + " " + data[i].value+"</p>";
            };
            $('#cli_household').html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line as mentioned below [Not mandatory]

```
$('#hh_id').change(function() { ... });

$('#cli_hh_id').change(function() { ... });
```

However, this event will only fire when the selector has lost focus, so you will need to click somewhere else to trigger that function.

Alternatively you can use other [jQuery events](http://www.see.ms/uKfNR) like keyup, keydown or keypress - depending on the exact effect you want.